# Refresh designer in Blend

Tags: xaml, expression-blend

Either I'm not as intelligent as I once believed or the UI in Blend is really this bad.

Is there any way to 'refresh' changes I've made to an XAML file in the designer? Something simple like changing 'Fill="Red"' to 'Fill="Blue"' does not show up in the designer unless I close and re-open the file.

Google and SO were sadly and surprisingly not helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I've ever had this problem. The only time I've had the designer not refresh was if I was tinking in code view, or if I had changed some code and not rebuilt.

Does it always do this? Do you have issues with any other WPF apps or any other UI glitches? I'm assuming this is Blend 2 or 3?

Comment: Blend 2, I haven't worked much with WPF so I can't say I've had much previous experience. This is also my first experience with Blend.

I'm using a XamChart from Infragistics WPF Controls product, if that helps at all.

Blend is also crashing like a drunken badger on angeldust.

Comment: I'll also add that you probably answered my question, that no there is not a button and that it is something screwy with my App/libraries :D.

Answer (score 0):

Changes in xaml are reflected on the Blend design surface for me. Preferably, you would change the fill using the properties panel.